# Why not place tsunami-height-prediction gauges in a straight line instead of zigzags?

Tags: tsunami, japan

I am watching [NHK World-Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHK_World-Japan)'s documentary [The Mystery Of The 40 Meter Tsunami](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BEi32c7Prv4), which analyzes the 40.5-meter tsunami at [Miyako, Iwate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miyako,_Iwate) that occurred during the [2011 Tōhoku earthquake and tsunami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_T%C5%8Dhoku_earthquake_and_tsunami). They mention authorities plan to install underwater gauges to assess the water pressure to estimate the tsunami height in the future, to avoid getting blindsided as they did in 2011.

[image]

The gauges are placed [as follows](https://youtu.be/BEi32c7Prv4?t=2575):

[image]

Why not place gauges in a straight line instead of zigzags?

Answer (score 1):

I think this comes down to a question of perspective.

You see zigzags, yes I see them too, but I also see numerous straight lines connected as a loop.

Looking at the big loop, I see 20 sub-perpendicular lines radiating out from the coast. Each line is approximately straight. I've marked them in red in the picture below. The yellow line marks the return of the loop. It would also act as an initial warning sensor line. Each sensor on the yellow line would more or less line up with one of the red lines and thus serve to extend each of the red lines.

Regarding sensors on the lines connecting the ends of the red line, why not? It's potentially more data, that could be useful.

[image]